# How to turn off auto-capitalization on the HTC One M8?

Tags: sms, htc

This is bugging me while texting. I don't see an option to turn it off in the text app's settings, or Settings -> Language & keyboard.

Here's the screen when I open settings from the keyboard:

[image: Text settings page]
And here's the submenu when I hit Advanced:

[image: Advanced text settings page]

Comment: Do you have a button on your on-screen keyboard that allows you to do capital letters?

Comment: Yes, so I can override the auto-capitalization each individual instance, but I want to turn it off in general.

Comment: Oh... Well that was what I was going to recommend. I don't know of a way to turn it off all the way.  Sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, on the stock HTC keyboard, you **cannot** turn off auto-capitalization. Consider *[Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en)*, which gives better customization options.

Comment: I'm able to access the menu by long-pressing the comma, but I don't see anything there referring to auto-capitalization.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of your keyboard settings screen?

Comment: Edited question to include.

Comment: See new answer.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks for the workaround! I'm liking Google Keyboard better in general anyway.